# Dash in python - callback error about scatter plot and dropdown

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm studying dash library.
This code showing the scatter plot when i select column in the data frame.
This works without any problem, but call back error occurs on the web page.

on the web, callback error updating spas-graph.figure
i can't understand why this error occurs.

```
[import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'depth' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'upper_value' : [1, 4, 6, 2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 4, 2],
    'middle_value' : [5, 3, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8],
    'down_value' : [6, 2, 1, 10, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 7]
})

col_list = df.columns[1:4]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = 'select-cd',
        options = [
            {'label' : i, 'value' : i}
            for i in col_list
        ]
    ),

    dcc.Graph(id = 'spas-graph')    

])

@app.callback(
    Output('spas-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('select-cd', 'value')]
)
def update_figure(selected_col):
   
    return {
        'data' : [go.Scatter(
            x = df[selected_col],
            y = df['depth'],
            mode = 'lines + markers',
            marker = {
                'size' : 15,
                'opacity' : 0.5,
                'line' : {'width' : 0.5, 'color' : 'white'}
            }
        )],
        
        'layout' : go.Layout(
            xaxis={'title': 'x_scale'},
            yaxis={'title': 'y_scale'},
            hovermode='closest'
        )
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the value parameter in your dropdown method. So when the server starts the first input it picks up is a None value.

You can solve it in two ways:

1. Add a default value in the Dropdown:
2. Handle None value in the callback method

   ```
    import dash
    import dash_core_components as dcc
    import dash_html_components as html
    from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'depth' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'upper_value' : [1, 4, 6, 2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 4, 2],
        'middle_value' : [5, 3, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 8],
        'down_value' : [6, 2, 1, 10, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 7]
    })

    col_list = df.columns[1:4]

    app = dash.Dash(__name__)

    app.layout = html.Div([

        dcc.Dropdown(
            id = 'select-cd',
            options = [
                {'label' : i, 'value' : i}
                for i in col_list
            ],
            value = col_list[0]
        ),

        dcc.Graph(id = 'spas-graph')    

    ])

    @app.callback(
        Output('spas-graph', 'figure'),
        [Input('select-cd', 'value')]
    )
    def update_figure(selected_col):
        if selected_col is None:
            selected_col = col_list[0]
        return {
            'data' : [go.Scatter(
                x = df[selected_col],
                y = df['depth'],
                mode = 'lines + markers',
                marker = {
                    'size' : 15,
                    'opacity' : 0.5,
                    'line' : {'width' : 0.5, 'color' : 'white'}
                }
            )],

            'layout' : go.Layout(
                xaxis={'title': 'x_scale'},
                yaxis={'title': 'y_scale'},
                hovermode='closest'
            )
        }
   ```